# populating a webform select list from a view?

Tags: views, webforms

I have a webform in D7 where I want the user to select a value from a dropdown list. These values I want to be dynamically updated from a view. How can I do this?

I found the [webform viewreference module](http://drupal.org/project/webform_viewreference), but it's D6. There is a [d7 port](http://drupal.org/node/1030426#comment-4464996) that someone made using coder, but, like author notes, I get an error when I try to view the form with the view reference webform component.

Are there any solutions out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the <strike>sandbox</strike> project [Webform Views Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views_select).

> This module will let you populate a webform select component with data from a view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your own module with a .js file.
You have to make a rfi form for that and through you js file take the values.

Suppose on your site you have to select a country and based on that country different values like course, SiteID,AccountID and campaignID need to be selected.

**In .js file you have to do:**

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.highwire_article_nav = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      var campus_settings = $.parseJSON(Drupal.settings.settings_campus.campus_data);
      $('select#edit-submitted-occupation').find('option').remove();
      $('select#edit-submitted-occupation').append($('<option>', {
        value: '- Select -',
        text : '- Select -'
      }));
      $('select#edit-submitted-country').change(function(e){
          var campus = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
          var campus_config = campus_settings[campus];
          var campus_courses = campus_config.courses
          $('[name="submitted[siteid]"]').attr('value', campus_config.siteID);
          $('[name="submitted[campaignid]"]').attr('value', campus_config.campaignID);
          $('[name="submitted[accountid]"]').attr('value', campus_config.accountID);
        $('select#edit-submitted-occupation').find('option').remove();
          $.each(campus_courses, function(index) {
            $('select#edit-submitted-occupation').append($('<option>', {
            value: campus_courses[index],
            text : campus_courses[index]
          }));
        });
      });
    }
  }
}(jQuery));
```

**In the rfi form give the values like** :

```
{"country_name":{"course_name":{"0":"Course_name_1","1":"Course_name_2"},"campaignID":"value_of_campaign_ID" , "siteID":"value_of_site_ID" ,"accountID":"value_of_account_ID"}} and so on.
```

Answer (score -1):

[EVA](http://drupal.org/project/eva) might work for that, however I haven't used it in this scenario.